# Variable/function with if-statement

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I want a menu showing links/buttons depending on the permissions of the account. And I don't want to copy/paste this code to every page. I use an if-statement to check if the link/button will show for the user who is logged in at the moment. How can I like create a variable or function to just print the menu that is on another PHP file?

Like this menu:

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>';

    if(condition) {
        echo '
        <a href="#">Link 5</a>';
    }

</div>
```

Comment: Just use echo/print in 'menu.php' and then include it where I need it in the code? Will that print the code?

Comment: either include or store you links in an array and loop over the array.

Comment: Where is the condition coming from? A session variable or what?

Comment: Aah sorry, feeling a bit dumb right now.. Thx @u_mulder :) Thought I had to echo it out or something. Never tried this before, but we learn every day. :)

Comment: @gtr1971 : The condition check with the database for permission on the account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your menu HTML in a file, and [`include`](http://php.net/include) it in every other page in which you want your menu to appear.

**menu.php:**

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>';

    <?php
    if(condition) {
        echo '
        <a href="#">Link 5</a>';
    }
    ?>

</div>
```

**foo.php:**

```
<?php

include 'menu.php';

# code ...
```

That way, the contents of `menu.php` will get evaluated and be put into your `foo.php` file as if it were copied and pasted.